# Cannot set custom domain name with Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have a custom domain name, let's say `example.co.uk`. I originally purchased it through 123 Reg but have now transferred to Route 53. I have setup a Hosted Zone for that domain name.

I have been looking at many guides but for the life of me I cannot set the custom domain name, I can only access my site through the Elastic IP.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you fully transfer the domain to Route53 or did you just change the name servers in 123reg to point to the Route53 name servers? If you fully transferred the domain, make sure you update the name server records in the Hosted Zone to match the name server records listed in the Route53 Registered Domains section.

To point your domain to your server you simply need to create an A record in the Hosted Zone that points to the Elastic IP. You also could have done that in 123reg without using Route53 at all.

Comment: I fully transferred. I'll double check name server records but pretty sure they are the same.. I have created an a record that points to my elastic IP, when I go to the domain name it just renders a 123 reg styled page with the domain name